# How to create a custom container of references?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, reference, qlist

**Disclamer:**

**I already understand that the C++ committee has it's reasons for not supporting this, so please no answers telling me "this is a bad idea", or anything of the sort, I mostly want to do this for fun, and I personally found a situation where I'd like to use it. Programmers will always argue about this type of thing, so please no arguing.**

**Qestion:**

Now to the point... I was wanting to use a QList, only to discover that C++ does not support containers of references, so I thought maybe I could create a custom container of references, that actually stored pointers under the hood (which is what references essentially are under the hood anyways). What would be the best way of doing this? (And I will not accept "there is no good way to do it" as an answer, let's be open minded people!)

**Answer:**

I managed to get an implementation working, and I think it works pretty good, I use a QList, but the concept should be the same for any container type. I created a Github Gist for it here: [ReferenceList.hpp](https://gist.github.com/tgaurnier/568cb85410fbadc63caa). Or you can view it in the answer below.

Even though I answered my own question, don't be afraid to post other ideas on how to accomplish this!

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: No, I just wanted to share my solution to this. That's not against the rules here is it?

Comment: You should write the question as a question, as if you were really asking it, and write answer to it as an answer. Think of the question text from the point of view of someone else who might also answer it.

Comment: OK, I'll edit it soon, as soon as I have a chance, also I found (with the help of someone on Qt forums) several issues, so I'll update my answer to the new implementation.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It's not so much solving a problem as it is solving a pet peeve, and I know I'm not the only one who is bugged by the fact that we can't have containers of references, one of my professors stated that this was one of his biggest pet peeves with C++. I know you can just as easily have a container of pointers, but that's not the point (no pun intended).

Honestly I mostly did this just to see if I could :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * ReferenceList.hpp                                                           *
 *                                                                             *
 * Copyright 2014 Tory Gaurnier <tory.gaurnier@linuxmail.org>                  *
 *                                                                             *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify        *
 * it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by *
 * the Free Software Foundation; version 3.                                    *
 *                                                                             *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,             *
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of              *
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the               *
 * GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.                         *
 *                                                                             *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License    *
 * along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.       *
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */


#ifndef REFERENCELIST_HPP
#define REFERENCELIST_HPP


#include <QDataStream>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QList>


/**
 * class ReferenceList
 *
 * Uses QList under the hood to store pointers, on the surface recieves and returns nothing but the
 * references.
 *
 * NOTE: Any method that calls it's QList<T*> counterpart with parameter T, T must not be const, if
 * it is then QList<T*> would have to be QList<const T *const> instead.
 */
template<class T>
class ReferenceList : public QList<T*> {
    public:
        // Forward declare iterators
        class const_iterator;
        class iterator;

        // Set iterators as friends
        friend class const_iterator;
        friend class iterator;


        ReferenceList() {}
        ReferenceList(const QList<T*> &other) : QList<T*>(other) {  }
        ReferenceList(const ReferenceList<T> &other) : QList<T*>(other) {  }
        ReferenceList(ReferenceList<T> &&other) : QList<T*>(std::move(other)) {  }
        ~ReferenceList() {}

        void append(T &value) {
            QList<T*>::append(&value);
        }

        void append(const ReferenceList<T> other) {
            QList<T*>::append(other);
        }

        const T & at(int i) const {
            return *QList<T*>::at(i);
        }

        T & back() {
            return *QList<T*>::back();
        }

        const T & back() const {
            return *QList<T*>::back();
        }

        iterator begin() {
            return iterator(iterator(QList<T*>::begin()));
        }

        const_iterator begin() const {
            return const_iterator(QList<T*>::begin());
        }

        const_iterator cbegin() const {
            return const_iterator(QList<T*>::cbegin());
        }

        const_iterator cend() const {
            return const_iterator(QList<T*>::cend());
        }

        void clear() {
            QList<T*>::clear();
        }

        const_iterator constBegin() const {
            return const_iterator(QList<T*>::constBegin());
        }

        const_iterator constEnd() const {
            return const_iterator(QList<T*>::constEnd());
        }

        bool contains(T &value) const {
            return QList<T*>::contains(&value);
        }

        int count(T &value) const {
            return QList<T*>::count(&value);
        }

        int count() const {
            return QList<T*>::count();
        }

        bool empty() const {
            return QList<T*>::empty();
        }

        iterator end() {
            return iterator(QList<T*>::end());
        }

        const_iterator end() const {
            return const_iterator(QList<T*>::end());
        }

        bool endsWith(T &value) const {
            return QList<T*>::endsWith(&value);
        }

        iterator erase(iterator pos) {
            return iterator(QList<T*>::erase(pos));
        }

        iterator erase(iterator begin, iterator end) {
            return iterator(QList<T*>::erase(begin, end));

        }

        T & first() {
            return *QList<T*>::first();
        }

        const T & first() const {
            return *QList<T*>::first();
        }

        /**
         * Inherited "from" methods are unsupported.
         */
        static ReferenceList<T> fromSet(const QSet<T> & set) = delete;
        static ReferenceList<T> fromStdList(const std::list<T> & list) = delete;
        static ReferenceList<T> fromVector(const QVector<T> & vector) = delete;

        T & front() {
            return *QList<T*>::front();
        }

        const T & front() const {
            return *QList<T*>::front();
        }

        int indexOf(T &value, int from = 0) const {
            return QList<T*>::indexOf(&value, from);
        }

        void insert(int i, T &value) {
            QList<T*>::insert(i, &value);
        }

        iterator insert(iterator before, T &value) {
            return iterator(QList<T*>::insert(before, &value));
        }

        bool isEmpty() const {
            return QList<T*>::isEmpty();
        }

        T & last() {
            return *QList<T*>::last();
        }

        const T & last() const {
            return *QList<T*>::last();
        }

        int lastIndexOf(T &value, int from = -1) const {
            return QList<T*>::lastIndexOf(&value, from);
        }

        int length() const {
            return QList<T*>::length();
        }

        ReferenceList<T> mid(int pos, int length = -1) const {
            return ReferenceList<T>(QList<T*>::mid(pos, length));
        }

        void move(int from, int to) {
            QList<T*>::move(from, to);
        }

        void pop_back() {
            QList<T*>::pop_back();
        }

        void pop_front() {
            QList<T*>::pop_front();
        }

        void prepend(T &value) {
            QList<T*>::prepend(&value);
        }

        void push_back(T &value) {
            QList<T*>::push_back(&value);
        }

        void push_front(T &value) {
            QList<T*>::push_front(&value);
        }

        int removeAll(T &value) {
            return QList<T*>::removeAll(&value);
        }

        void removeAt(int i) {
            QList<T*>::removeAt(i);
        }

        void removeFirst() {
            QList<T*>::removeFirst();
        }

        void removeLast() {
            QList<T*>::removeLast();
        }

        bool removeOne(T &value) {
            return QList<T*>::removeOne(&value);
        }

        void replace(int i, T &value) {
            QList<T*>::replace(i, &value);
        }

        void reserve(int alloc) {
            QList<T*>::reserve(alloc);
        }

        int size() const {
            return QList<T*>::size();
        }

        bool startsWith(T &value) const {
            return QList<T*>::startsWith(&value);
        }

        void swap(ReferenceList<T> &other) {
            QList<T*>::swap(other);
        }

        void swap(int i, int j) {
            QList<T*>::swap(i, j);
        }

        T & takeAt(int i) {
            return *QList<T*>::takeAt(i);
        }

        T & takeFirst() {
            return *QList<T*>::takeFirst();
        }

        T & takeLast() {
            return *QList<T*>::takeLast();
        }

        /**
         * Inherited "to" methods are not supported.
         */
        QSet<T> toSet() const = delete;
        std::list<T> toStdList() const = delete;
        QVector<T> toVector() const = delete;

        T & value(int i) const {
            return *QList<T*>::value(i);
        }

        T & value(int i, T &default_value) const {
            return *QList<T*>::value(i, &default_value);
        }

        bool operator!=(const ReferenceList<T> &other) const {
            return QList<T*>::operator!=(other);
        }

        ReferenceList<T> operator+(const ReferenceList<T> &other) const {
            return ReferenceList<T>(QList<T*>::operator+(other));
        }

        ReferenceList<T> & operator+=(const ReferenceList<T> &other) {
            QList<T*>::operator+=(other);
            return *this;
        }

        ReferenceList<T> & operator+=(T &value) {
            QList<T*>::operator+=(&value);
            return *this;
        }

        ReferenceList<T> & operator<<(const ReferenceList<T> &other) {
            QList<T*>::operator<<(other);
            return *this;
        }

        ReferenceList<T> & operator<<(T &value) {
            QList<T*>::operator<<(&value);
            return *this;
        }

        ReferenceList<T> & operator=(ReferenceList<T> &other) {
            QList<T*>::operator=(other);
            return *this;
        }

        ReferenceList & operator=(ReferenceList<T> &&other) {
            QList<T*>::operator=(std::move(other));
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator==(const ReferenceList<T> &other) const {
            return QList<T*>::operator==(other);
        }

        T & operator[](int i) {
            return *QList<T*>::operator[](i);
        }

        const T & operator[](int i) const {
            return *QList<T*>::operator[](i);
        }


        class iterator : public QList<T*>::iterator {
            public:
                iterator() {  }
                iterator(const typename QList<T*>::iterator &other)
                    : QList<T*>::iterator(other) {  }
                iterator(const iterator &other) : QList<T*>::iterator(other) {  }
                T & operator*() const { return *QList<T*>::iterator::operator*(); }
                T * operator->() const { return *QList<T*>::iterator::operator->(); }
                T & operator[](int j) const { return *QList<T*>::iterator::operator[](j); }
        };

        class const_iterator : public QList<T*>::const_iterator {
            public:
                const_iterator() {  }
                const_iterator(const typename QList<T*>::const_iterator &other)
                    : QList<T*>::const_iterator(other) {  }
                const_iterator(const const_iterator &other)
                    : QList<T*>::const_iterator(other) {  }
                const_iterator(const iterator &other)
                    : QList<T*>::const_iterator(other) {  }
                T & operator*() const { return *QList<T*>::const_iterator::operator*(); }
                T * operator->() const { return *QList<T*>::const_iterator::operator->(); }
                T & operator[](int j) const { return *QList<T*>::const_iterator::operator[](j); }
        };
};


/**
 * Implement QDebug << operator so that it will print out values rather than pointer addresses (do
 * to it implicitly converting to QList<T*>).
 */
template <class T>
QDebug operator<<(QDebug debug, const ReferenceList<T> &list) {
    debug.nospace() << '(';
    for(typename QList<T>::size_type i = 0; i < list.count(); ++i) {
        if(i) debug << ", ";
        debug << list.at(i);
    }

    debug << ')';

    return debug.space();
}


/**
* QDataStream << ReferenceList<T> should have same output as the QDataStream << QList<T>.
*/
template<class T>
QDataStream & operator<<(QDataStream &out, const ReferenceList<T>& list) {
    out << quint32(list.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) out << list.at(i);
    return out;
}


/**
* Make sure QDataStream >> is not callable, there is no scenario where it would be useful with a
* ReferenceList.
*/
template<class T>
QDataStream & operator>>(QDataStream &out, const ReferenceList<T>& list) = delete;

#endif
```

Comment: I completely overhauled the implementation, it should work perfectly now.